# try to extract one tweet's id information after creating an API object

Tags: python, api, tweepy

I'm still new in python and i was trying to extract one tweet's id information after creating an API object.
so the code was :

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = 'hidden'
consumer_secret = 'hidden'
access_token = 'hidden'
access_secret = 'hidden'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

# to test it
exp_tweet = api.get_status(archive.tweet_id[1000], tweet_mode = 'extended')
content = exp_tweet._json
Content
```

the output is :

```
NameError: name 'archive' is not defined
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: As the error says. You don't have any `archive` initialised

Comment: bear with me please...how can i  initialised it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take this [tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1294917318405836802), I can find it's id in the URL witch is "1294917318405836802"

You can update your code and try to retrieve it

```
id_ = "1294917318405836802"
exp_tweet = api.get_status(id_, tweet_mode = 'extended')
content = exp_tweet._json
```